# how to change the alertdialog box style in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am just trying to build a alertdialog for my android application.

what I actually want is a dialog box like this:
[image]

whose positive and negative button are filled across dialog box

but I always get something like this:

[image]

and these two buttons stick together at the right corner of dialog box

can anybody tell me what to do to change the alertdialog from the second one to first one?

many thanks

Comment: <style name="dialogtheme"  parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">  
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>  
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle.DeviceDefault</item>  
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>  
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>  
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>  
</style>   use this theme for you dialog.

Comment: How are you creating dialog? please show your code

Comment: it is no use actually

Answer (score 1):

For that You need to create custom dilogbox Like this 
Dialog xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Dismiss" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And In your Activity :

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

            //setting custom layout to dialog
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.cusotm_dialog_layout);
            dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

            //adding text dynamically
            TextView txt = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            txt.setText("Put your dialog text here.");

            ImageView image = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info));

            //adding button click event
            Button dismissButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
            dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set customized layout to alert dialog by using setView(view) method like this:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
 View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_layout, null);
 dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
 AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
 alertDialog.show();
```